# How to retain combobox selected background color, inside grid panel once move to next row..or can say focus out?

Tags: c#, javascript, combobox, ext.net

Unable to retain the selected background color inside grid panel once move to next row..its working fine outside the panel.I want to retain the combo-box selected background color after moving from that row also...

```
<ext:XScript ID="XScriptdd1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
var applyFilter = function(field, grid) {

            var c = field.value;
            if (c == '1') {
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundImage = "none";
            } else if (c == '2') {
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundColor = "#FF8080";
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundImage = "none";
            } else if (c == '3') {
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundImage = "none";
            } else if (c == '4') {
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundColor = "#C2FFA3";
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundImage = "none";
            } else if (c == '5') {
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundImage = "none";
            } else if (c == '6') {
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundColor = "Gray";
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundImage = "none";
            } else {
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                field.el.dom.style.backgroundImage = "none";
            }

           grid.focus(true);

        };       

    </script>
</ext:XScript>

<ext:GridPanel ID="GrrdERLPnl" runat="server" EnableColumnMove="false" ButtonAlign="Center"
    Border="true" TrackMouseOver="true" Height="500" Width="900" AutoScroll="true"
    AutoWidth="false" Padding="20">
    <Store>
        <ext:Store ID="StoreERL" runat="server">
            <Reader>
                <ext:ArrayReader>
                    <Fields>
                        <ext:RecordField Name="category" Type="String" />
                        <ext:RecordField Name="ComboField" Type="int" />
                        <ext:RecordField Name="comments" Type="String" />
                    </Fields>
                </ext:ArrayReader>
            </Reader>
        </ext:Store>
    </Store>
    <Plugins>
        <ext:EditableGrid ID="EditableGrid1" runat="server" />
    </Plugins>
    <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <ext:Column Header="Level 1 ERL" DataIndex="category" Width="350" Align="Center" />
            <ext:Column Header="ERL Maturity" DataIndex="ComboField" Width="250" Align="Center">
                <Editor>
                    <ext:ComboBox Flex="1" runat="server" ID="cmboErlMaturity" NoteAlign="Top" ItemSelector="div.search-item"
                        Width="150" Height="100" TriggerAction="All" >
                        <Items>
                            <ext:ListItem Text="Select Maturity " Value="0" />
                            <ext:ListItem Text="A " Value="1" />
                            <ext:ListItem Text="B " Value="2" />
                            <ext:ListItem Text="C " Value="3" />
                            <ext:ListItem Text="D " Value="4" />
                            <ext:ListItem Text="E " Value="5" />
                            <ext:ListItem Text="N/A " Value="6" />
                        </Items>
                        <Listeners>
                            <Select Handler="applyFilter(this,#{GrrdERLPnl})" />
                            <%--<Change Handler ="applyFilter(this,#{GrrdERLPnl})" />--%>
                        </Listeners>
                        <Template runat="server">
                            <Html>
                            <tpl for=".">
                                    <div class="search-item">            
                                        <h1 style="text-align:center;  background-color:{[values.value == 0 ? 'white' : values.value == 1 ? 'Red' : values.value == 3 ? 'Yellow': values.value == 2 ? '#FF8080': values.value == 4 ? '#C2FFA3': values.value == 5 ? 'Green': values.value == 6 ? 'Gray' : 'black']}">{text}</h1>
                                   </div>
                                  </tpl>
                            </Html>
                        </Template>
                    </ext:ComboBox>
                </Editor>
            </ext:Column>
            <ext:Column Header="Comments" DataIndex="comments" Width="250" Align="Center">
            </ext:Column>
        </Columns>
    </ColumnModel>
</ext:GridPanel>
```

code behind

```
private object[] Data
  {
     get
     {
        return new object[]
            {
                new object[] { "Technical Requirements", 0, "Comments to test" },
                new object[] { "Technical Requirements", 0, "Comments to test" },
                new object[] { "Technical Requirements", 0, "Comments to test" },
                new object[] { "Technical Requirements", 0, "Comments to test" },
                new object[] { "Technical Requirements", 0, "Comments to test" },
                new object[] { "Technical Requirements", 0, "Comments to test" },
                new object[] { "Technical Requirements", 0, "Comments to test" },
                new object[] { "Statemenet of Work", 0, "Comments to test1" }

            };
    }
}

  private void BindData()
  {
    var store = this.GrrdERLPnl.GetStore();

    store.DataSource = this.Data;
    store.DataBind();
  }
```

Once we set focus on grid with grid.focus(true);
Its working fine on FF and chrome but on IE8 getting js error: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Any help is highly appreciated in advance!

Comment: Unable to set background coloe after selection in grid panel...its working fine outside the grid panel...Is I set grid.focus(true) its working fine but with js error 'Object doesn't support this property or method'.Any help is highly appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is controversial to talk about a GridPanel as a focusable element. I would recommend to remove this line:

```
grid.focus(true);
```

As for the fact that the background-color disappears, it is because of a GridPanel's row is re-rendered after editing. A ComboBox is re-rendered as well.

As a solution, I can suggest to add this AfterRender listener for the ComboBox:

```
<AfterRender Handler="applyFilter(this);" />
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply....Its working once focus out from combo-box means  little bit time taking....have been tried this one but it was little bit slow and unusual behavior and not pleasant experience as user's point of view.Please suggest if is there any other workaround!! that we can try...

Comment: Do you mean that it works slow and unstable with that AfterRender listener? I have not noticed anything in FireFox. Please clarify, what browser do you test with?